# Laravel Eloquent get all categories of restaurants?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to get all categories of restaurants.

My models:

**Restaurant**

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'restaurant_categories_relation','restaurant_id');
}
```

**Category**

```
public function restaurants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Restaurant::class,'restaurant_categories_relation', 'category_id');
}
```

In my controller:

```
$restaurants = Restaurant::where('district_id', $request->district)->paginate(8);
$categories = $restaurants-> ????;
```

Please help me do this, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `has()` like :

```
Category::has('restaurants')->get();
```

That will return the `categories` who are related with the `restaurants`.

---

Try also the use of `whereHas` like :

```
$users = Category::whereHas('restaurants', function($q){
    $q->->where('district_id', $request->district)->paginate(8);
})->get();
```

---

Since you've already a Collection we can't query the categories  so I suggest  adding a function to scope that inside the `Restaurant` model like :

```
public static function getCategoriesOfRestaurants($restaurants)
    $categories = [];

    foreach($restaurants as $restaurant){
      array_push( $categories, $restaurant->categories->pluck('id')->toArray());
    }

    return Category::WhereIn('id', array_unique($categories))->get();
}
```

Then just call it when you get the `$restaurants` collection :

```
$restaurants = Restaurant::with("categories")->where('district_id', $request->district)->paginate(8);
$categories  = Restaurant::getCategoriesOfRestaurants($restaurants);
```

**Note:** The use of `with("categories")` when getting the collection will query All the related categories in the first query so the `foreach` loop will not generate any extra query just looping through the already fetched data, and finally we will get the collection of categories in the return statement.

Comment: Thank you, but $restaurants is collection get from where clause.

Comment: So you want to get the related categories with the collection of `$restaurants` ?

Comment: Yes, I want that!

Answer (score 1):

use `with()` method for eagerloading, that provides you get all categories in a single query

```
$restaurants = Restaurant::with("categories")->where('district_id', $request->district)->paginate(8);
foreach($restaurants as $restaurant){
  foreach($restaurant->categories as $category)
     {{$category}}
  }
}
```

if you want to use categories outside of the loop, then assign these categories to a variable

```
foreach($restaurants as $restaurant){
  $categories = $restaurant->categories;
}

// do something with $categories
```

Comment: Thank you! But I want show all category outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you, but I think this script will very slow if I have a lot of restaurants!

Comment: @justcntt interesting

Answer (score 1):

Your relation should be
`Restruant.php`

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'restaurant_categories_relation','restaurant_id','category_id');
}
```

then in you controller method just wirte
`$restruants = Restruant::with('categories')->get();`

It should return you collection of all restruants with all related categories.